# iOS share extension binary rejected

Tags: ios, deployment, appstore-approval, share-extension

We have developed an iOS application with a share extension. The main functionality of the share extension is to get the web URL and scrape data from that URL. As all the functionalities are taken care through the share extension, the only functionality of the app is to log in users to the app. But when we submitted our app to the Apple review, they have rejected our app saying the below message ,

> Guideline 4.2 - Design - Minimum Functionality
>
> We found that the usefulness of your app is limited by the minimal
>   amount of content or features it includes.
>
> Next Steps
>
> We encourage you to review your app concept and incorporate different
>   content and features that are in compliance with the App Store Review
>   Guidelines.
>
> We understand that there are no hard and fast rules to define useful
>   or entertaining, but Apple and Apple customers expect apps to provide
>   a really great user experience. Apps should provide valuable utility
>   or entertainment, draw people in by offering compelling capabilities
>   or content, or enable people to do something they couldn't do before
>   or in a way they couldn't do it before.
>
> Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage
>
> We noticed that your app requires users to register or log in to
>   access features that are not account-based.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to let users freely
>   access your app’s non account-based features.
>
> Apps may not require users to enter personal information to function,
>   except when directly relevant to the core functionality of the app or
>   required by law.
>
> You should allow users to freely access your app’s non account-based
>   features. For example, an e-commerce app should let users browse store
>   offerings and other features that are not account-based before being
>   asked to register, or a restaurant app should allow users to explore
>   the menu before placing an order. Registration must then only be
>   required for account-specific features, such as saving items for
>   future reference or placing an order.

My questions are,

1.) How we can overcome these issues and re-submit the app to apple 
      review?

2.) Is it possible to upload the share extension to the app store 
      without embedding inside an app?

Comment: Why do users need to log in to the app? Do you need personal information from them to provide your service?

Comment: @wvteijlingen we have a web application which manages all the account details, then those users can download the app and share details for their account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem comes from the understanding of what your app doing.

You can schedule a phone call with the reviewer or another guy from Apple and try to explain what your application doing. Or you can deploy a new version of your application where the user can do more things and have more features.

I had a similar problem with an app which was some kind of newsletter and Apple rejects the app until we didn't add functionalities like comments, likes and etc.

Good luck with your app, everything depends on the guy who will review the app and how big is his willingness to understand the app.